# C/C++ - HWInfo - libhd - How to get the name list of all available devices?

Tags: c++, c, list, device

On **Linux**, one can use command "hwinfo" (*after installing it*) in *Terminal* to print a lot of device information. While this is nice, I'd also like to utilize **libhd** (*included in hwinfo*) to get device information, device names to be exact. How can one get the name list of all available devices and then print the name list, in C/C++?

Comment: Not really a good question, do you have anything specific or just want us to read the documentation for libhd and paste you some code?

Comment: @r_ahlskog: I wanted to keep this question quite general-purpose. The main problem I'm having is with the array "hd_data_t::hd". Function "hd_get_input_devices" takes in a pointer to a structure named "hd_data_t". Everything's fine here, but how do I know how many elements are there in hd_data_t::hd? I guess it's an array of all the devices, but getting the number of elements in it bugs me. How do I get the amount of devices?

Comment: Now that is a better question, I'll go look at how it works and come back. Buy my guess is either there is a parameter giving you the length or the return value of the function is.

Answer (score 1):

From your comment above... If you just wanna know the number of elements from a struct, let's say your struct is hd_data_t, you may use

```
int nSize = sizeof(hd_data_t)/sizeof(hd_data_t[0]);
```

Comment: Oh, it really was that simple. I'll to get rid of the linker errors and maybe answer my question with a complete answer I was looking, you know, for those who happen to have same problems as I do. Or maybe, if you can, you could offer a complete answer. Either way, thanks, Owen!